# python callback if some value changes becase of user set a marker in a leafmap map

Tags: python, parameters, callback, python-decorators

I use a map with the leafmap python module. My goal is to trigger a function if the user sets a marker in the map. With m.user_roi it is possible to get the last drawn feature coordinates. When the map first is initialized the m.user_roi will yield a None. So i have to set the m.user_roi in the first place.

#### Leafmap Object

```
import leafmap
m = leafmap.Map(center=(50, 9.5), zoom=6, height="400px", width="800px") 
m.user_roi = {'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {}, 'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [9.5, 50.0]}} # Set initial user_roi "last drawn element"
m
```

What I want now is that if the user set a marker in the map, a function is called. I believe this is called a callback. So I looked up the [leafamp](https://leafmap.org/) module, but they haven't implemented something like an event or similar to let my python code known when a marker is set. Is there a python module that handles such a problem for me?

What I found was [param](https://param.holoviz.org/index.html). They have something like a @depend decorator.

```
location = m.user_roi
@param.depends('location', watch=True)
def update_data():
    #...do something when location changes
```

But this only works when I manually change the location value. What is the right Term in programming context when i try to observe a value and their changes?